# Find records with odd characters in names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

I have a large list of records that were imported from an excel document some time ago that no longer exists. We've started to find that some of the names in the document have characters that must have been converted during the import. Some examples:
± © Ð € Ù _ l Ì » ñ

I'm not sure how many odd characters there could be, and there is alot of records. Is there any way I would be able to do a search on the records for other characters like these? The import was done in a JSON style format, so the record is a long string like this example (spaced for easier viewing)

```
{
      "email_address":"fakemail@mail.com",
      "values":{
           "FNAME":"©Johñ",
           "LNAME":"SmÌth»"
      }
}
```

I'm using MSSQL Server 2008 R2, or can do C# if a solution is simpler that way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "odd"? The `ñ` and `Ù` and `Ì` are perfectly valid characters for names, and these days, are also valid in domain names.

Comment: In my circumstance, they are not accepted as valid characters when this JSON is used later on by other code, making them "odd" to me.

Comment: Even if they are naturally a part of someone's name? Or a domain name, in which case changing it to remove an accent will technically not be the same domain name and hence won't be their email address?

Comment: I'm not arguing that they are not REAL and VALID characters. I am saying that in my situation, they are causing issues. I'm not going to go judge and jury here and change peoples names, I just need to find the related records.

Comment: Ok then ;-).  I will post an answer in a moment with both the correct way and the way that you need ;-)

Comment: This is an `NVARCHAR` field, right?

Comment: It's actually a VARCHAR(MAX) field.

Comment: And the collation of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that this will find characters that are valid in both names and email addresses *but* do not seem to be valid in your system, you should use the following `LIKE` statement:

```
WHERE tab.col LIKE '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.,@:{}" _]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;
```

What is important here is the `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2` (unless the field is already using a binary collation). But if the field is not using a binary collation, then not specifying one here for the `LIKE` predicate will miss characters such as `ñ` and other accented characters since they usually equate to non-accented characters (e.g. `n` = `ñ`).

Example:

```sql
SELECT col
FROM (VALUES ('©Johñ'),
             ('{ "email_address":"fakemail@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"SmÌth»"  } }'),
             ('{ "email_address":"fakemail2@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"Jones"  } }'),
             ('{  }'),
             ('f_f'),
             ('g-g'),
             ('Johñ f')
     ) tab(col)
WHERE tab.col LIKE '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.,@:{}" _]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;
```

With the `COLLATE` clause the `'Johñ f'` row is identified, but without the COLLATE, that row appears to be "valid".

---

Alternatively, if you have both:

- Unicode data (i.e. `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` fields)
- A system that accepts real-world data (and does not erroneously reject names and email addresses containing non-US English characters, or convert them to US English equivalents)

then a T-SQL `LIKE` operator cannot work because of the great variety of letters across many languages. In this case you will need a Regular Expression since those can handle character classes, which are logical groupings of characters. Of course, RegEx isn't offered natively in T-SQL, but you can still get this functionality via SQLCLR. You can find numerous examples around of how to code this, or you can just download the Free version of the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library (which I created, but most of the RegEx functions -- and many others -- are free) which includes a **RegEx_IsMatch** function that can be used as follows:

```sql
SELECT tab.col,
       CASE WHEN tab.col LIKE N'%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.,@:{}" _]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [LikeOperator],
       SQL#.RegEx_IsMatch(tab.col, N'[\W-[-\{\} @:",.]]+', 1, N'IgnoreCase')
               AS [RegEx_IsMatch]
FROM (VALUES (N'©Johñ'),
             (N'{ "email_address":"fakemail@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"SmÌth»" } }'),
             (N'{ "email_address":"fakemail2@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"Jones" } }'),
             (N'{  }'),
             (N'f_f'),
             (N'g-g'),
             (N'k,k'),
             (N'ＷＩＤＥ'),
             (N'simple-email@place01.co'),
             (N'Johñ f')
     ) tab(col);
```

Returns:

```
col                                                                         LIKE    RegEx
-----------------------                                                     -----   ------
©Johñ                                                                           1       1
{ "email_address":"fakemail@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"SmÌth»" } }          1       1
{ "email_address":"fakemail2@mail.com", "values":{ "LNAME":"Jones" } }          0       0
{  }                                                                            0       0
f_f                                                                             0       0
g-g                                                                             0       0
k,k                                                                             0       0
ＷＩＤＥ                                                                         1       0
simple-email@place01.co                                                         0       0
Johñ f                                                                          1       0
```

What the `[\W-[-\{\} @:",.]]+` pattern means is: one or more characters (`[]+`) that are "non-word" characters (`\W`) *except* (`-[]`) the following list which are ok: `-`, `{`, `}`, , `@`, `:`, `"`, `,`, and `.`.

Comment: This worked awesomely. Thanks so much for the help srutzky!

Comment: @Blankdud no problem. And if you, or anyone, ever needs to allow for real-world data, I added a section that handles it via RegEx :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can find unexpected characters using `like` with "not" and a character class:

```
select email_address
from t
where email_address like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]%';
```

Comment: I tried this : '%[^a-zA-Z0-9@.{":,}_]%' and received all the records.          
    
Do JSON characters such as  { " : , } need to be escaped? Or can I just toss those within the braces?

Comment: If you want to *ignore* them, then throw them between the square braces.  Remember that starting the list with a caret (`'^'`) means "does not match this character".

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match on all lines that contain an 'odd' character. Any additional characters that you don't want to be considered odd can be added to the character class to exclude from the search.

```
/^.*[^a-zA-Z\s\[\]\{\}'":@.,_].*$/gm
```